# Proper accessibility or ARIA role for a resize handle

Tags: html, accessibility, user-experience, wai-aria

When building either an interface for shape manipulation

[image: Google Slides selected rectangle shape example with resize handles]

or for resizing a text box

[image: StackOverflow text area "grippie" resize handle circled in red]

how would one go about making these controls accessible? I'm not sure it's possible given the existing [WAI-ARIA roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#role_definitions). There are some examples and provisions for regular drag and drop conventions but nothing obviously related to resizing, rotating or any kind of transformation or manipulation like that.

Answer (score 6):

For shape manipulation, check out powerpoint and how you can use it with just a keyboard.  You can TAB to the different objects on your slide (in edit mode, not presentation mode) and then use the arrow keys to move the box around.  Shift+arrow lets you resize the object.  Alt+arrow lets you rotate it.

For your second example, resizing the text box, we usually have a splitter between two panels and use [`role=separator`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#separator) and [`aria-orientation=horizontal`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-orientation) and `tabindex=0`.  You can tab to the object then use the arrow keys to move the splitter to resize.

I would respectfully not recommend using a spinbutton or slider.  As a screen reader user, if I hear spinbutton or slider, there's a certain behavior that I expect with those objects and having it be the resize object would be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if those possibilities are a good idea. But I'll put it here as an answer, because it does not fit into the comment section.

One possible solution could be the role `spinbutton` with `aria-valuemax`, `aria-valuemin` and `aria-valuenow`. At first thought this might be wrong because you are looking for a draggable element. But on the other hand, you want to control the current value of `left`, `top`, `bottom`, `right` or `width` and `height`, and this is a number, so it would fit the purpose of a `spinbutton` and would allow a user to precisely control the possible values. My concerns are that it would not match the real number of visible control elements (e.g. the corners of the rectangle), and I'm not sure if this might be a problem.

Another possible solution could be to define it as a `slider` because a slider has a similar purpose. But my concern about defining it as slider is, that it isn't a visually noticeable slider, and I don't know if this might result in confusion.

Dragging does IMHO not really fit the requirement. It, on the one hand, has `execute` for the drop effect, but requires a target, and does not really indicate the purpose of the dragging.